# How can we allow dots in ASP.NET MVC urls?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a website developed in MVC 5 that perform search in inventory and the url is like this

```
http://localhost:56099/search/SQUARE
```

This url works, it redirects to Search controller and Index action with search query as SQUARE and gives the correct result. But, if I enter 2 dots as a search query it just takes me to my root page. The url will be like this

```
http://localhost:56099/search/..
```

it's strange because same thing works when passing single dot or multiple dots, so I can't find any technical reason why it is getting neglected.

I have done following things in Web.Config:

1. `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` for accepting others characters also in search query.
2. `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"`

But no success and I can't find any real reason for this weird behaviour. Any advice.

Answer (score 0):

you should register the search route in your "RouteConfig.cs" file

```
routes.MapRoute(
              "SearchRoute",
              "Search/{*pathinfo}",
              new { controller = "Search", action = "ActionName"});
```

Comment: I have added - 
`routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Search",
               url: "Search/{filter}/{pageNo}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", filter = UrlParameter.Optional, pageNo = UrlParameter.Optional });`

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem with `..`, because `..` in your case is detected as relative URL, which indicates moving up to the parent directory(or root in your case), essentially stripping off everything up to the previous slash in the the Base URI.

UrlRoutingHandler in `web.config` should help you.

```
<system.webServer>    
  <handlers>      
    <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" 
         type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler, 
               System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
         path="/Search/*" 
         verb="GET"/>      
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Then every URL starting with `/Search` will be considered as  MVC URL.

Also you could try:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```